# Can not display Image from MVC view file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-pages

To use in more complex page I have been trying to display one simple page on my view (details.cshtml) but it persistently does not show. I tried the different piece of codes as below.

```
<div>
<img src="@Url.Content("~/CustomStorage/Patients/1/Pictures/20190416/penguins.jpg")" />
<img src="~/CustomStorage/Patients/1/Pictures/20190416/penguins.jpg" class="dker" alt="..." />
<img src="C:\Users\Ata\source\repos\Enterx\Enterx\CustomStorage\Patients\1\Pictures\20190416\penguins.jpg" class="dker" alt="..." />
```

None of those 3 sources actually display picture, only image icons.
And when I right click and choose "open  image in new tab" first two gives 
"
This localhost page can’t be found 
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:21014/CustomStorage/Patients/1/Pictures/20190416/penguins.jpg
" error.
last one opens "about:blank#blocked" page.
I understand the last one is access problem. 
But why can not I display with first two? It has been days and I have been reading people have no problems.
Is It maybe my VS2017 version or actual solution has a problem?

Comment: I use the @Url.Content("~/path/") option all of the time.  Are you sure that "CustomStorage" is a folder in the root of your MVC web project?

Comment: Can you show the solution explorer tree?

Comment: oi @Bhargav Rao! Are you joking buddy. I wrote that not to gain anything. People were still trying to help and I needed to explain that I already solved it. I guess you consider everybody is like you: looking for easy wins!!!